# MS Access Dlookup #Error or ?Name value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've got a foreign key lookup in the form of the following two tables -

```
tblApplications
    applicationId
    applicationName

tblApplicationsManagement
    application (references tblApplications.applicationId)
```

I have a text field on a form that is setup with tblApplicationsManagement which I want to reference the applicationName through the relationship.

I've tried this -

```
=DLookup("[applicationName]", "tblApplications","[applicationId] = [tblApplicationsManagement]![application]")
```

And all I get is #Error on the initial Form entry and everything comes up blank.

edit - the following returns #Name? on all entries

```
=DLookUp("[applicationName]","tblApplications","application=" & [applicationId])
```

To make sure I'm capturing all the right info.  I'm trying to populate a Plain Text field with the `[applicationName]` from the foreign key.  the Text Field name is `fieldApplicationName`

NOTE for any viewers - The solution is correct.  The issue was on the SQL side having a column called "application" which isn't specified as a keyword but it must be somewhere either on the SQL or MS Access side.

Comment: Get a test version of `DLookUp()` working without all the variables.  Then work from that to your goal.  Also:  Make an ordinary query that does what you want; then convert that by steps into a `DLookup()` statement.  Also:  Use `Debug.print` and breakpoints to make sure you are getting values from the form fields.  The last part of your `DLookUp()` looks like it has problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form includes a text box named *txtApplication* which is bound to the `tblApplicationsManagement.application` field in your form's *Record Source*, this should work as the *Control Source* for the problem text box ...

```vb
=DLookup("[applicationName]", "tblApplications", "[applicationId] = " & [txtApplication])
```

Note I presumed `tblApplicationsManagement.application` and `tblApplications.applicationId` are both numeric datatypes.  If they're text, you'll need to add quotes ...

```vb
=DLookup("[applicationName]", "tblApplications", "[applicationId] = '" & [txtApplication] & "'")
```

Comment: They are both integers so no quotes needed.  I'm not understand the [txtApplication].  If I do the following I still get an #Error - `=DLookUp("[applicationName]","tblApplications","[applicationId] = " & [application])`

Comment: I think part of the confusion reading this is the Text Box properties has no Bind Value only Control Source.  I'm entering the Control Source values and getting no results.  If I make a new text field on the form it will initiallly display `UnBound` but then I set the control source as above with the same problem.

Comment: OK.  Let's try this test, please:  Make a copy of your form.  In that copy, add a text box and name it *txtApplication*.  Set its *Control Source* to the `application` field in your form's *Record Source*.  Switch from Design to Form View and verify the new text box properly displays the `application` value for each row in the form.  If it doesn't, what happens instead?  If it does, switch back to Design View and use the `DLookup` expression I suggested as the *Control Source* of the text box where you want to display `applicationName`.

Comment: you're correct.  If I create a new Text Field and set the Control Source as `application` I get the integer so success there.  I then tried both your DLookup values using `[fieldApplicationName]` which is the Text Box name.  All I get is #Error.  Changed it to `[application]` which is the FK column still no luck.

Comment: I got it!  Not doing the Dlookup though!  I had to goto the form and do a query builder and set all the form values to include the link with the other table.  I could then reference the applicationName directly as the Control Source!

Comment: Please double-check the table name, `tblApplications`.  If that name is correct, make sure it includes fields named `applicationName` and `applicationId`.  Also, if either of those fields is a lookup or multi-value field, please describe.

Comment: Aha, problem name issue!  Those can be downright maddening.  Use Allen Browne's free utility to see whether your database includes other such problems waiting to bite you: [Database Issue Checker Utility](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html)